# install GCP sdk and problem is ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in 
import bootstrapping
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 45, in 
from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import local_state
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/local_state.py", line 39, in 
from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import installers
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 28, in 
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/base.py", line 31, in 
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/display.py", line 37, in 
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display_taps
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/display_taps.py", line 46, in 
from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_printer_base
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_printer_base.py", line 47, in 
from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_projector
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_projector.py", line 71, in 
import proto  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/proto/**init**.py", line 15, in 
from .enums import Enum
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/proto/enums.py", line 21, in 
from proto.marshal.rules.enums import EnumRule
File "/Users/mamounadel/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/proto/marshal/rules/enums.py", line 15, in 
from typing import Type
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'

Comment: How did you install GCP sdk ? Have you followed the official instructions (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explanation to this question, so I will presume this is about cloud vision (but most of the libraries went through a similar change). 

As per the [Migration Guide](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/index.html), the enums and types modules have been removed. You can access all the types under vision directly.

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1
request = vision_v1.GetProductSetRequest(name="name")
```

[Source](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/57#issuecomment-702794506)